# Spawn a node at random coordinates in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm trying to spawn a node I've created at random coordinates. So far, I've made the attempt by doing the following:

```
- (SKShapeNode *)createTargetNode
{

  int maxXCoord = CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame);
  int maxYCoord = CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame);

  int x = arc4random()% maxXCoord + 40;
  int y = arc4random()% maxYCoord + 40;

  SKShapeNode *target = [SKShapeNode new];
  CGMutablePathRef circle = CGPathCreateMutable();
  CGPathAddArc(circle, NULL, x, y, 5, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
  target.path = circle;
  target.fillColor = [SKColor redColor];
  target.strokeColor = [SKColor redColor];
  NSLog(@"%d, %d", x, y);
  return target;
}
```

Sometimes the node appears on the screen, sometimes it doesn't. I guess it's going out of bounds. How can I fix that? The orientation of the phone is landscape, so do the coordinates change?

Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

Here are some coordinates that have been plotted:

```
2014-02-14 17:54:09.629 reactions[16096:70b] 221, 402
2014-02-14 17:54:10.990 reactions[16096:70b] 273, 542
2014-02-14 17:54:11.586 reactions[16096:70b] 88, 299
2014-02-14 17:54:14.660 reactions[16096:70b] 69, 306
```

Only `(88, 299)` and `(69, 306)` are actually plotted. 
Here's the link to the image (I can't post it yet, I don't have enough reputation):

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Here's my main view controller. Pretty standard, just loading the `SKScene`.

```
#import "DKViewController.h"
#import "DKPlayScene.h"

@implementation DKViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    SKScene * scene = [DKPlayScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    [skView presentScene:scene];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

And here's the implementation file for the SKScene:

```
#import "DKPlayScene.h"
#include <stdlib.h>


@interface DKPlayScene ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) SKLabelNode *scoreLabel;
@property bool *gameHasStarted;
@property int  *score;

@end

@implementation DKPlayScene

- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
  if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

    self.gameHasStarted = NO;
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];
    self.scoreLabel = [SKLabelNode new];

    self.scoreLabel.text = @"High Score:";
    self.scoreLabel.fontSize = 10;
    self.scoreLabel.position = (CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 70));
    [self createTargetNode];
    [self addChild:self.scoreLabel];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  [self addChild:[self createTargetNode]];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {

}

#pragma mark - Private

- (SKShapeNode *)createTargetNode
{

  int maxXCoord = self.frame.size.width;
  int maxYCoord = self.frame.size.height;

  int circleWidth = 6;

  int x = arc4random() % (maxXCoord - (circleWidth / 2));
  int y = arc4random() % (maxYCoord - (circleWidth / 2));

  SKShapeNode *target = [SKShapeNode new];
  CGMutablePathRef circle = CGPathCreateMutable();
  CGPathAddArc(circle, NULL, x, y, circleWidth, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
  target.path = circle;
  target.fillColor = [SKColor redColor];
  target.strokeColor = [SKColor redColor];
  NSLog(@"%d, %d", x, y);
  return target;
}
```

Comment: where do you add the node (node position is relative to its parent) and do you change its position? Also, you forgot to CGPathRelease(circle).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D
The node is added in the touchesBegan method:

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  [self addChild:[self createTargetNode]];
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sometimes the node appears on the screen, sometimes it doesn't. I guess it's going out of bounds. How can I fix that? The orientation of the phone is landscape, so do the coordinates change?

It's because the height and width used are wrong.

In your code, `[MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size]` will always return size in **portrait** orientation, even though it's landscape on the device / emulator, it's happen because you put it on `viewDidLoad`.

If you want to get the size of current orientation (**landscape**), place the code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, not in `viewDidLoad`.

Go to "ViewController.m", replace the `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

Documentation link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: I understand your logic with subtracting by the radius. That was my logic with the +40, guess I meant to subtract. However, it still wont fit all the circles onto the screen.

I've updated my question to include a screenshot of the app.

Comment: I've try it, and all of generated circle always plotted. can you show more code / more clue ? so we can help you why some circles didn't plotted

Comment: @dkind please check my answer. I've updating it, it should work